# find an analytic continuation for specific values

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

The function $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ is expanded into a Taylor series in a neighbourhood of the point a where $|a|< 1$. For what values of a the newer expansion provides the analytic continuation of $f(z)$ outside of the unit circle?

So my understanding of a is that it represents the centre in the circle of convergence for the Taylor series. So I need to choose values for a that recentres $f(z)$ outside of the unit disk.

If I let $a = 0$, then I will just have my original function, $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ . So, will choosing $-1<a<0$ and  $0<a<1$ ensure that I am outside of the unit circle?

Comment: since you know that $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$, you can easily compute its Taylor series at $a$ : $f(a+z) = \frac{1}{1-z-a} = \frac{1}{1-a}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{1-a}} = ?$

Comment: So I want my radius of convergence to be greater than 1. Does this mean  z > 1 - a which means    -1 < a < 0?